# Query to fetch data from same table, multiple columns

Tags: sql-server

Can someone help me in this.

I am explaining with below examples -

No, not exactly.  I have one table in which data is collected in form or revenue charged to the customer and the payment made by the customer.  So lets say the revenue charged is 3 times i.e. 5000 each on 18-12-2016, 19-12-2016 and 20-12-2016 and payment done by the customer is on 19-12-2016 with amount 7000.00 and then on 20-12-2016 with amount 2000.00.  The entry in this table is inserted as -

TableName - Temp1

CustidId     Amount      pdate          amount2
1            5000.00     18-12-2016     0.00
1            5000.00     19-12-2016     0.00
1            0.00        19-12-2016     7000.00
1            5000.00     20-12-2016     0.00
1            0.00        20-12-2016     2000.00

I need output of this table in below format -

Custid    InDate      Outdate     TotalRev   PaymentDate      PaymentAmount
1         18-12-2016  20-12-2016  15000.00   19-12-2016       7000.00
1         18-12-2016  20-12-2016             20-12-2016       2000.00

This data is for 1 customer and same way there can be multiple customers so based on custid the data of revenue and collection has to be shown.  The second row in above example can have In Date and out date as blank also but TotalRev column in second row has to be blank or zero.

Kindly help me in this.

Comment: Are you trying to choose the max amount2 from each date or are you summing all amount2 values per day?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    Id
    , pdate
    , SUM(amount2) AS amount2
    , SUM(Amount) AS Amount
FROM
    Temp1
GROUP BY
    Id, pdate;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query like this...

```
SELECT ID, Pdate, max(Amount) as Amount, max(amount2) as Amount2)
   from temp1 group by Id, Pdate
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [group by clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to aggregate your records.

The group should contain a list of columns, from which you want all unique combinations.

You can combine the group by with one or more [aggregated functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx), like [SUM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), [MIN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179916.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [MAX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187751.aspx).  Passing a column to these functions will return, for example, the sum of that column for each given combination returned by your group by clause.

```
-- Total amount and amount2 for each combination of Id and PDate .
SELECT 
    t1.id,
    SUM(t1.amount)    AS amount,
    t2.pdate,
    SUM(t2.amount2)   AS amount2
FROM
    temp1 t1
        join temp1 t2     on  t1.id = t2.id 
                          and t2.amount2 >0 where t1.amount1 >0 
GROUP BY
    t1.id,
    t2.pdate
;
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understand you need a sum per `pdate` column, right?

If so you can probably use this query:

```
select t1.id, SUM(t1.amount),t1.pdate, SUM(t1.amount2) from temp1 t1
group by t1.id, t1.pdate
```

Comment: This query will not run.

Comment: You need a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Thanks guys, I added later in edit. Sorry about that.